# String formatting, with Regex - Remove given character, and insert newline

Tags: regex, string, format, notepad++, space

I have a file full of URLs in a weird format, characters separated by a space character.

```
h t t p : / / w w w . y o u t u b e . c o m / u s e r / A S D        
h t t p : / / m o r c c . c o m / f  r  m / i n d . p h p ? t o p i c = 5 7 . 0
```

I would like to make it look like :

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/ASD
http://morcc.com/frm/ind.php?topic=57.0
```

I use notepad++, and I think regex could take care of this problem for me, unfortunately I don't know regex.
I want to remove the ' ' character (space) between the characters, and leave them in listed format, so replacing /s with '' is not a solution, because it becomes a mess :/
I think I should also insert a /n BEFORE "http" occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just replace a space ' ' with an empty string ''? Replacing \s is not working how you want because newlines are also matched.

If that doesn't work you could, as you say, replace `\s` with '' and then replace `http` with `\nhttp`.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea, I dont know how I did not think of this.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is fairly basic. Check out the examples page. The second example seems to have what you're looking for: http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

EDIT: Also, I assume you know this, but just to be sure, regex itself will not do what you want. What language are you planning on using regex with, so that people can provide more detailed responses?

Regex reference page [Bookmark it ;)] - http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: I'M using notepad++ software, and there is a option to use regex patterns. Thank you.